# Python: call count on mocks fails for parallel execution via multiprocessing

Tags: python, unit-testing, parallel-processing, mocking

I am trying to test a simple module for parallelization. This module provides a simple function `run_tasks(tasks, use_multiprocessing)`. My simple test consists of generating a list of tasks using the MagicMock class, calling run_tasks and testing if all mocks have been called exactly once.

In the case of specifying a serial run, all the mocks get called once. However, in the case of a parallel run, the mocks have a call count of zero. I suppose this a problem of the mock module, because if the tasks contain a print statement, this will be executed for both, serial and parallel run.

Here is the test code (Note: `test_run_tasks_in_parallel` fails whereas `test_run_tasks_serially` is green):

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import mock

from src.stochastic_simulation.util.embarrassing_parallelization import run_tasks
from src.stochastic_simulation.simulation.task import Task


class TestRunTasks(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.functions_to_run = [mock.MagicMock() for i in range(0, 9)]
        self.test_tasks = [Task(function, None) for function in self.functions_to_run]

    def test_run_tasks_in_parallel(self):
        run_tasks(self.test_tasks, use_multiprocessing=True)
        for function in self.functions_to_run:
            function.assert_called_once()

    def test_run_tasks_serially(self):
        run_tasks(self.test_tasks)
        for function in self.functions_to_run:
            function.assert_called_once()
```

Here is the module

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def run_task(task):
    task.run()


def run_tasks(tasks, use_multiprocessing=False):
    if use_multiprocessing:
        available_processors = mp.cpu_count() - 1
        print "Distributing tasks among {} processors".format(available_processors)

        pool = mp.Pool(processes=available_processors)
        _ = pool.imap_unordered(run_task, tasks, chunksize=1)

    else:
        print "No multiprocessing"
        for task in tasks:
            task.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem see [mock.patch and multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492977/mock-patch-and-multiprocessing/65499545#65499545)

Solution is to replace `mock.MagicMock()` with `SharedMock()` https://github.com/elritsch/python-sharedmock